# Find the probability in the box.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $3$ boxes, each contains $n$ mangoes. A person takes a mango from one randomly chosen box. This procedure is repeated until one of the boxes becomes empty. Find the probability that two other boxes contain one mango each.

I am new in a probability theory. I know that its conditional probability problems but need help to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the probability that a random sequence of $3n-2$ letters A, B, C contains two letters $n-1$ times and the other $n$ times.

Now the question becomes combinatorics. There are $3^{3n-2}$ possible sequences. Do you know how to calculate how many have $n-1$ As, $n-1$ Bs and $n$ Cs? (Once you have this you need to multiply by $3$ because any of the three letters can be the extra one.)

The general formula for arrangements of $r_1$ of one letter, $r_2$ of another, ... and $r_k$ of the last is
$$\frac{(r_1+r_2+\cdots+r_k)!}{r_1!r_2!\cdots r_k!}.$$

Comment: thanks, actually no,

Comment: would you please guide me? I know it would a binomial form but don't know exactly how to calculate it.

Comment: It's actually a multinomial rather than binomial (because there are more than two boxes). There's an explanation of these at https://brilliant.org/wiki/multinomial-coefficients/

Comment: so would it be  \binom {n!}{3}{2} ?

Comment: \binom {n}{3} \binom {n}{2}   \binom {n}{1}

Comment: Note that you haven't got all the sequences because the boxes are limited to $n$ not $3n$.

Comment: then how many have n−1 will have?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at this in reverse. If you take all the mangoes out, including the final ones, the reverse process, which has the same probability profile is to fill all the boxes.

Now the situation you want happens only if in the reverse problem the first three mangoes are put into different boxes. And this is easier to solve.

Comment: can you plz help to solve or write a formula which fits here?

Comment: @HarronZarron I think you need to do some work, because you will only learn to solve problems like this if you think about them yourself. If $n=1$ there is only one option. For larger $n$ the first mango can go in any box. The next mango goes into one of the two remaining boxes $(2/3)$ and the third mango in the remaining box.